# Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: mongodb

I am using ubuntu 20.04
I have tried following solutions:
Solution 1:
First remove the mongodb using following commands:-

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Now reinstall the mongo again.

Solution 2:
Most probably unit mongodb.service is masked. Use following command to unmask it.

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongod
```

and re-run

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Solution 3:
You are missing a 'b' I think?

```
sudo service mongod start
```

should be

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Some more solutions are there but not working for me.

Comment: How did you install mongodb?

Comment: I installed mongodb by following this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-on-ubuntu    @Joe

Comment: Did apt acutally create a mongod.service file somewhere?

Comment: Yes it did but it was locked. Actually I found the solution. I just unlocked the file and it worked.

Comment: @SaketSuraj please share what made it work. I'm facing similar issue

Comment: @IstiyakTailor Hey I saw your comment after a long time today and I don't remember the exact command that I used but you can just search for a command that will unlock any file in linux and then you can restart the mongod service.

Comment: @SaketSuraj Unlocked what file? Please share your full solution, or there's no point to this question page.